# Random Password Generator on Python

Tags: python, passwords

I am trying to create a random password generator.
My question is "How can I add random digits and symbols to the password?"
Right now this is my code, as you can see it only gives me random letters.

```py
a = random.SystemRandom() 

length = 10

alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits

password = str().join(a.choice(alphabet) for _ in range(length))

print(password)
```

Comment: What do you mean by *symbols*?

Comment: I ran your code and got: `sycsX5PxBk` which seems to be letters and numbers. Is this wrong?

Comment: Something like  "!" or "-" , that makes the password more difficult.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You are already building the ``alphabet`` yourself. What problem do you have adding other desired symbols the same way?

Comment: Did you mean:`alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concat to the end

```
symbols = "*!@#$%^&"
for i in range(1): #change the number to the desired amount of symbols to add to the end
    password += a.choice(symbols)
```

or if you want them randomly placed:

```
symbols = "*!@#$%^&"
alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + symbols*2 #adding them in twice to reduce the probability of getting a password without them
```

As stated by quamrana you can also use `string.punctuation` in place of `"*!@#$%^&"`